# Prolog repeating solutions on symmetric relations

Tags: prolog, relation, symmetric

Consider this small program:

```
married(bill, hillary).
spouse(X, Y) :- married(X, Y); married(Y, X).
likes(X, Y) :- spouse(X, Y).
```

Now I want to evaluate a goal

```
?- likes(X, Y).
X = bill
Y = hillary ?;
X = hillary
Y = bill
yes
```

Is there a way to prevent repeating on this symmetric relation when backtrack and still preserve symmetry for goals like `?- likes(hillary, X).`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to define `spouse/2`:

```
married(bill, hillary).
married(tom, mary).
married(sam, linda).

spouse(X, Y) :-
     \+ married(X, Y) -> married(Y, X) ; married(X, Y).
```

So if there's no way to make `married(X, Y)` true, then it will try `married(Y, X)`. Otherwise, `married(X, Y)`.

```
| ?- spouse(X, Y).

X = bill
Y = hillary ? ;

X = tom
Y = mary ? ;

X = sam
Y = linda

(1 ms) yes
| ?- spouse(tom, Y).

X = tom
Y = mary

yes
| ?- spouse(X, tom).

X = mary
Y = tom

yes
```

It would appear on the surface that the following, slightly simpler, predicate may be equivalent, but it will not find all the solutions:

```
spouse(X, Y) :-
     married(X, Y) -> true ; married(Y, X).

| ?- spouse(X, Y).

X = bill
Y = hillary ? ;

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

**ADDENDUM**

Building on Sergey's observation:

```
| ?- Y = bill, spouse(X, Y).

X = hillary
Y = bill

yes
```

But:

```
| ?- spouse(X, Y), Y = bill.

no
```

This result is inconsistent because by confining `spouse/2` to unique solutions that consider symmetrical solutions redundant, the predicate is essentially saying that only one of `spouse(bill, hillary)` and `spouse(hillary, bill)` can be true at any given time. If the first argument is pre-defined to be `bill`, that then means the second argument must be `hillary`. If neither argument is instantiated and `spouse(X, Y)` indicates the solution `X = bill` and `Y = hillary`, then a subsequent query of `Y = bill` fails.

So, again as @Sergey indicated in his comment, this kind of predicate must be used with caution, understanding that its logical meaning is somewhat limited and even self-contradictory in some contexts.

Comment: Some caution with usage is needed: `Y = bill, likes(X, Y).` will succeed, but `likes(X, Y), Y = bill.` will fail.

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko that "defect" may be an unavoidable side-effect of defining `spouse(X, Y)` as being true only for unique solutions in `X` and `Y` including their permutation. Once an `X` and `Y` pair are established, then their commutation is by definition false. It's really an odd way to define a `likes` or `spouse` predicate (as @false alludes to in his answer).

Comment: @lurker: When you define relations, certain things simply cannot be.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to define a predicate such that it still retains its relational properties *and* fulfills your wishes, as @SergeyDymchenko observed in a comment.

It is not clear to me why you want this anyway. Maybe you want to reduce output? Then simply ask another query:

```
?- spouse(X,Y), X @=< Y.
```